# get point on edge of sphere given angles

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry

I have looked at every stackoverflow answer for the answer to this question. None worked. How do I get the point on the edge of a sphere given two angles?

```
Y
|    Z
|   /
|  /
| /   
|/________ X
```

I am using **three.js**. Say I have the above axis. I have the angle `xang` that is the *pitch*. I have the angle `yang` that is the *yaw*. I have a radius named `r`. How do I get a point on the edge of the sphere?

Comment: Do you know any trigonometry?

Comment: I am learning it in school, but I have only been taught how to get a point on the edge of a circle, not a sphere.

Comment: `x = radius * sin(yaw) * cos(pitch)`, `y = radius * sin(pitch)`, `z = radius * cos(yaw) * cos(pitch)` ... some may need to be negated though ... e.g. `= -radius * ...`

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! My problem was that the `pitch` angle was actually flipped around, so I had to do `360 -  xdeg` to make it work.

Comment: wouldn't `y = -radius * sin(pitch)` result in the same? because `cos(-pitch) == cos(pitch)` but `sin(-pitch) == -sin(pitch)` - so only `y` would need to be negated

Comment: The thing you're asking about was implemented in Three.js years ago. The `THREE.Spherical()` object and `.setFromSpherical()` method of `THREE.Vector3()`.